# Costs & licensing for TFS + VS2013Pro vs MSDN

Tags: tfs, licensing, visual-studio-2013, msdn

I need to equip a 3x developer team with VS2013Pro and TFS Server. We don't have anything we can upgrade from so starting from scratch.

My local Microsoft re-seller has repeatedly given me confusing information about what I need to purchase and I think he doesn't actually know. (wasn't even aware the 2013 was available)

Is this sufficient to get my team up and running?

```
1x TFS Server
3x Visual Studio 2013 Professional
```

Or do I need to buy this as well?

```
3x TFS CALs
```

Alternatively, am I likely to be better off $-wise getting an MSDN subscription which covers the team?

```
MSDN Subscription of some sort, covering 3x developers
```

Is there some generic online re-seller I can purchase through in Australia, or at least look for a better price from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing / software pricing, not programming or software development. See the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion & research it appears the following is the answer - for teams of 5 or less, with projects small enough to fit into the SQL Express edition, we can use the TFS Express edition with Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Therefore, in our scenario only one purchase is necessary:

```
3x Visual Studio 2013 Professional
```

Comment: You can also give http://tfs.visualstudio.com/ a look too.